# Removing div's from page structure

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to just remove the **page-wrapper** div, but can't seem to find the `.phtml` file to do so. I have seen that you should edit the `default.xml` file in your theme, but there has to be some way to edit the container of the page right?

I was digging in container phtml and found this line `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>` and assume that is pulling in the classes such as page-wrapper, page-header and more. Does anyone know how to remove the **page-wrapper, page-header, panel**, etc classes?

Comment: you want to create your own custom header?

Comment: I really want to create a custom wrapper. I just didn't know if I can change magento's base page structure. I know in magento 1.9 you could do it easy, but it seems impossible in 2.*

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header"></div>
...
</div>
```